# REGEX : Extract group of number where digits are more than 3

Tags: regex

HI I have a question regarding REGEX.

This sounds very simple and I remember doing it but somehow it got deleted and I am finding it hard to get it back.

I want to extract group of numbers from one line.

If the count of digits > 3 - select that.

**EG:
ga3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/i0ndex.php?&t0oken=abf540063shakk**

This line can be different everytime but there will be only 1 group of digits with more than 2 digits.

**OUTPUT: 540063**

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you are looking for the code as well but `\d{3,}` is the regex for any sequence of three or more digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\d{3,}` where 3 is the minimum number of digits. You an take a look at the following python code

```
import re
var= "ga3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/i0ndex.php?&t0oken=abf540063shakk"
pattern = re.compile(r'\d{3,}')
for match in pattern.findall(ver):
    print(match)
```